# Error on initalization of PyLatex Table

Tags: python

My goal is to create a floating table with `PyLatex`, to do this I want to use the class `Table`. But when I initialize a `Table` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "table.py", line 18, in <module>
    table = Table('rc|cl')
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

This is really confusing as I consider `'rc|cl'` as 1 argument. To make sure I make nothing wrong I executed a script from [Nullege](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40p%40y%40PyLaTeX-HEAD%40examples%40example.py/5/pylatex.Table/python), which results in the error above.

Comment: What does `table = Table()` do?

Comment: Then the table is initialized, but I get the error `'Table' object has no attribute 'add_hline'`. I think the example is wrong.

Comment: shouldn't it be `Tabular` instead of `Table`?

Comment: `Tabular` is a different class. A `Table` is "A class that represents a table float." (https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/latest/pylatex/pylatex.table.html). But I think that I got a false understanding on how a `Table` should work. BTW with `Tabular` I got no problems, they are just not floating.

Comment: `Tabular` is the actual table. Wrap it in `Table` to make it floating.

Answer (score 1):

As Feodoran mentioned in his comment the Tabular must be wrapped inside a Table to make it float.

```
doc = Document()

with doc.create(Table()):
   with doc.create(Tabular("llr")) as tabular:
      tabular.add_row(("Foo", "Bar", "Foobar"))
      tabular.add_hline()
      # etc
```